# click on "DONE" button on softkeybord how to go next activity android

Tags: android

hey can any one help me to go to next activity via next click on soft key board,means i have two option one using button in my lay out and second is using soft keyboard next button means when i have enter the text in edit text and click on next on soft keyboard want to go next activity.

my xml is for text entry in edit text..pls ignore it..

Comment: didnt u already ask this question today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, there is not a specific keydown event for that next button as you saying, but try it with KEYCODE_UNKNOWN may be it will help u. i havent tried but u can, like below:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN){
        // now start your activity here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: not working :( actually i had change android soft keyboard button to "NEXT" using android:imeOptions="actionNext" and i want when i click on it go to next activity,but NEXT button i think use for go to next edit text box in android so how to go next activity on clicking of next in soft keyboard ?thanks

Comment: ok try keyCode==Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE